# Can I make a connecting flight in Baku Airport (GYD) in 45 minutes and do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, gyd

I am planning to catch a trip home from Beijing (PEK) to Copenhagen (CPH) in august, and the cheapest one I can find is a "three-legger" through Baku (GYD) and Berlin (TXL) with Azerbaijan Airlines. The thing is, there is only 45 minutes between landing in Baku and departing for Berlin. (assuming there are no delays - I have no experience with this airline).

1. Will this be enough time for me to get from the arrival gate to the departure gate?
2. Since both flights are with the same airline, they should be aware of connecting passengers and wait for them in case of flight delay, yes? Or am I being optimistic?
3. Also, will I need to collect my baggage and check it back in (in which case I'm sure I don't have time to make the flight)?
4. And finally, do I need a visa to transfer between flights (EU citizen, if that matters)?

Comment: Are these flights on a single ticket? I'm seeing a minimum connection time of 1 hour generally at GYD. Can you give the flight numbers?

Comment: Flight numbers are J268 and J263. It's a single ticket from Beijing to Copenhagen I found on kayak.com.

Comment: the layover for that flight in GYD is 1:45

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. PEK-J268-GYD-J263 TXL has a layover of 1 hour 45 minutes in GYD. This is above minimum connection time and should be fine. However, Azerbaijan airlines (J2) only has one flight per day from GYD to TXL so if you do miss it, they would most likely rebook on you on the next day and you would have to stay overnight. It is possible that they could also rebook you via another route and occasionally might rebook you to another airline, but I would doubt that.
2. Airlines rarely wait for connecting passengers these days, but might if there are a considerable number arriving from a connecting flight.
3. Your bag should be checked through to your destination and you shouldn't have to pick it up in Baku.
4. Enter your citizenship and travel details in [Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) and it will tell you whether you need a visa. Timatic is the system the airlines use to determine whether you require a visa and thus won't carry you without it.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that answers all my questions! I checked the Azerbaijan Airlines website and they also list it as a 1h45m connection. I guess it must be an error on the vendors side.